# Magento won't load correct site and admin panel can't be accessed

Tags: magento2, admin-panel

We`re currently trying to investigate a shop we didn't set up. After trying minifying the css/js the shop stopped loading the correct landingpage. only page that is showing up is the /coming page. We also made a backup. Unfortunately we can't restore it, as we aren't able to access admin backend. I took a look into the config files and found "fronted:admin123" but that also doesn't work.

How could we find out what to do in order to get into admin backend?
https://zazzkids.com

That's the domain we are on, server is super slow...

Comment: Yes, we've got ssh access. I checked `backend/frontName`, which said admin123. I think I can see the admin panel loading for a split second. But it always ends up at /coming again. `pub/.htaccess` looks normal to me, I tried setting the shop into developer mode. didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

- `/comming` is a non Magento page. So the shop root is redirecting you away.  (check nginx/apache rules, `check pub/.htaccess` if the server uses apache, check `pub/index.php` for possible redirects).
- I assume you have SSH access? Login and check `app/etc/env.php`. Check for `backend/frontName` to see where the backend admin panel is located.